# Find $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_{n}$ where $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{a_n} + \frac{1}{n + k}$?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Define the sequence $a_n$ by the following.

> $k>0, a_1 > 0,$
>
> $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{a_n} + \frac{1}{n + k}.$

Please tell me that this sequence $a_n$ converges or not.

If $a_n$ converges, prove that $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_{n} = 1$.

(If you know $a_n$ converges, Let $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_{n} = L$.

$L = \frac{1}{L} + 0$. So $L = 1$)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f_n : (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ be defined by

$$ f_n(x) = \frac{(n+k)x}{n+k+x} + \frac{1}{n+k+1}. $$

Then it is easy to check that $f'_n(x) = (n+k)^2/(n+k+x)^2 < 1$ and $f_n(1) = 1$. Thus

- $x < f_n(x) < 1$ if $x \in (0, 1)$.
- $x > f_n(x)$ if $x > 1$.

Also notice that $a_{n+2} = f_n(a_n)$. Thus it follows that both $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n-1})$ are monotone bounded sequences and hence they converge.

Let us write $\alpha = \lim a_{2n}$ and $\beta = \lim a_{2n-1}$. From the recurrence relation, we know that $\alpha \beta = 1$. We also notice that

- Each $f_n$ is concave, thus for any $x > 1$, we have
  $$ f_n(x) \leq f_n(1) + f'_n(1)(x - 1) = 1 + \left( \frac{n+k}{n+k+1} \right)^2 (x - 1) $$
  and hence $a_{n+2} - 1 \leq \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n+k+1} \right)^2 (a_n - 1)$. In particular, if $a_{n_0} > 1$, then recursively applying this inequality gives
  $$ 1 \leq a_{n_0 + 2j} \leq 1 + \prod_{i = 0}^{j-1} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n_0 + 2i +k+1} \right)^2 (a_{n_0} - 1). $$
  It is not hard to show that the right-hand side converges to 1 as $j \to \infty$.
- If $a_n < 1$, then it is easy to check that $a_{n+1} > 1$.
- Combining these two results, we must have either $\alpha = 1$ or $\beta = 1$, and this completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

We rewrite the given relation into $ (n+k)a_{n}a_{n+1}-a_{n}-(n+k)$ and this motivates to define $f_{n}(x)=(n+k)x^2-x-(n+k)$.

Let $x_{n}$ be the positive root of $f_{n}(x)=0$.

Then $x_{n}=[1+(1+4(n+k)^2)^{1/2}]/2(n+k)$ so $ 1<x_{n+1}<x_{n}$ for all $n$ in $N$.

If $a_{1}<x_{1}$ then $a_{2}>x_{1}>x_{2}$ cuz $a_{2}=1/a_{1}+1/(1+k)>1/x_{1}+1/(1+k)=x_{1}$. So WLOG, we assume $a_{1}>=x_{1}$.

First, if $a_{n}>= x_{n}$ then $a_{n}>= a_{n+1}$ cuz $a_{n+1}-a_{n}=[a_{n}+n+k-a^{2}_{n}(n+k)]/[a_{n}(n+k)]$ of which numerator is the substitution of $a_{n}$ in $-f_{n}(x)$ and $f_{n}(x)$ is positive for $x>= x_{n}$.

If there's no $n$ s.t the inequality between $a_{n}$ and ${x_{n}$ is conversed for $n>= m$ for some $m$ in $N$ then $[a_{n}]_{n>= m}$ is monotone and bounded so it converges.

In case there exist $n$ s.t the inequality between $a_{n}$ and ${x_{n}$ is conversed, that is, $a_{j}>= x_{j}$ for $j<n$ and $a_{n}<x_{n}$, then $a_{n+1}>x_{n}>x_{n+1}$ cuz $a_{n+1}=1/a_{n}+1/(n+k)>1/x_{n}+1/(n+k)=x_{n}$ and $a_{n}$ is in the interval $[1/a_{n-1},a_{n-1}]$. Also $a_{n-1}>a_{n+1}$ cuz $a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}=[a_{n-1}+(n-1+k)-a^{2}_{n-1}(n+k)/[(a_{n-1}+(n-1+k))(n+k)]$ which is obviously negative.

Now collect $a_{n}$s s.t $a_{n}>= x_{n}$ and rename it {$b_{j}$} then $b_{j}$s are a subsequence of $a_{j}$s and monotone decreasing and larger than 1(cuz each $b_{j}>=x_{m}>1$ for some m). So {$b_[j}$} is convergent. Since $b_{j}<x_{m}$ for some m(cuz $b_{j}=a_{n}>=x_{n}$ for some n and $a_{n+1}=1/a_{n}+1/(n+k)<=1/x_{n}+1/(n+k)=x_{n}$ or $a_{n+2}=[a_{n}(n+k)]/[a_{n}+(n+k)]+1/(n+1+k)=a_{n}-a^{2}_{n}/[a_{n}+(n+k)]+1/(n+1+k)<a_{n+1}$ one of which is essentially $b_{j+1}$ and both are smaller than $x_{n}$) and $x_{m}$ converges to 1, {$b_{j}$} converges to 1. And for all those $a_{l}$s s.t $a_{l}<x_{l}$, each $a_{l}$ is in the interval $[1/b_{j},b_{j}]$ for some $j$, as we observed in the previous paragraph, which shows those $a_{l}$s also converges to 1.

I think this proof has advantage of not using differentiations so I posted despite of poor coding skills and really sorry for that but this is my first post here and I can't find proper codes anywhere. Would you let me know plz? Thank you guys :)